# Kali Linux Live USB access to main SSD

Tags: usb, kali-linux, ssd

I just installed Kali Linux on a Live USB and when I'm booting from it I can see all of my files from my main SSD from which I'm running Windows 10.

What should I do so that my SSD won't be visible when I'm booting from the Live USB?

Also, can Kali write on the SSD?

Answer (score 0):

Your hard drive partitions will be visible when you live boot. However, as far as I can recall, they are never mounted by default. If you want to completely hide the SSD, remove it from your system.

Yes. Kali *can* write to SSD if and only if you mount your SSD drive.